# How to make join model inherit values from joined models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a track number field in my Track model and want to copy this to the ReleasesTrack join model's position field on create and update. I've tried the following in the the ReleasesTrack model but nothing happens.

```
class ReleasesTrack < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :number_tracks
  before_update :number_tracks

  def number_tracks
    self.position = self.track.position
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

I was using acts_as_list to set the position but there's some weird ordering occurring as a result of the tracks being nested_attributes and the sql statements being executed in no particular order, so I need to set the position myself.